# Using a string array to get information from a list of multiboxes

Tags: c#, string, combobox, selectedindexchanged, assembly-references

So I have an array that has the first portion of comboboxes on an order form. the comboboxes hold data (x1, x2, x3, x4), and are named ketchupCount, mustardCount, etc...

What I am trying to do is use the array normalCondoments array + Count to generate the correct combobox name to set the SelectedIndex value to -1 which is unselected.  Eventually It will get the value, not set it, and print it to a string...

The expected code should read
ketchupCount.SelectedIndex

```
    string[] normalCondoments = { "ketchup", "mustard", "mayo", "ga",
                                  "lettuce", "tomato", "pickles", "onion" };
    foreach (var nCondoment in normalCondoments)
                {
                    string str = nCondoment + "Count";
                    MessageBox.Show("letter:" + nCondoment);
                    str.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
```

The error I am getting is:

"String does not contain a selected definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no accessable extension for 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'string' ncould be found."

VS doesnt give a fix for this, I have looked and looked, but havent found something similar to this error.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a multibox? Are you refering to a ComboBox? A ListBox? Can you specify the platform you're using? Are you trying to use an object's reference with a string set to its name?

Comment: Are you referring to a `<html:multibox>`?

Comment: I apologize it is the combo box, editing above to reflect correct terminology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference of a Control using the [Container.Controls[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection) collection.
This collection can be indexed by a `Int32` value or a `String`, representing a Control's name.

In your case, if the ComboBoxes are all direct children of the Form, your code could be:

```
string[] normalCondoments = { "ketchup", "mustard", "mayo", "ga",
                              "lettuce", "tomato", "pickles", "onion" };

foreach (var nCondoment in normalCondoments) {
    (this.Controls[$"{nCondoment}Count"] as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Otherwise, replace `this` with the actual container.

If instead these controls are children of different containers, you need to find them.
In this case, use the Controls collection's [Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) method, specifying to `searchAllChildren`:

```
foreach (var nCondoment in normalCondoments) {
    var cbo = (this.Controls.Find($"{nCondoment}Count", true).FirstOrDefault() as ComboBox);
    if (cbo != null) cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: You Jimi are a genius, this has been driving me crazy for several days, I will post the working code in al ittle bit

Comment: I did have to add the container name instead of "this"
`code`int answer;
            foreach (var nCondoment in normalCondoments)
            {
                answer = (nCondomentsContainer.Controls[$"{nCondoment}Count"] as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;
                string str = nCondoment + "Count";
                if (answer > -1)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(nCondoment +" " + (answer+1));
                   rCondoments = rCondoments + nCondoment + " " + (answer + 1) + "\n";
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

This is not javascript, you must use the variable not a its name

```
ketchupCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
mustardCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
mayoCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
gaCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
lettuceCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
tomatoCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
picklesCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
onionCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Or create an array to hold them

```
var normalCondoments = new multibox[] {ketchupCount, mustardCount, mayoCount, gaCount,
     lettuceCount, tomatoCount, picklesCount, onionCount};
foreach(var nCondoment in normalCondoments)
  nCondoment.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: I dont need an array to hold them, I just need to display them.  The issue is that, I cant use a variable string to loop through all 8,  I tried calling string[] normalCondoments = {ketchupCount, mustardCount, blah}  It is still reading as a string.